# How to add external data as new columns in Power Query? Followup question about syntax

Tags: powerquery

I saw this question answered but the solution I did not work for me. Below is my query but the new column displays "error" for each row of new column:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fnGetParameter("File Path")), null, true),
    Table1 = Source{[Item="Devices_PLC_ID",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Table 1 Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Table1, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Table 1 Blank Rows", "Index", 1, 1),
    Table2 = Source{[Item="Devices",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Table 2 Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Table2, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Table 2 Blank Rows", "PLC_ID", each #"Added Index"[PLC_ID]{[Index]})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are attempting to do, but this code:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Table 2 Blank Rows", "PLC_ID", each #"Added Index"[PLC_ID]{[Index]})
```

creates a column called [PLC_ID], with a formula (each ... ) that refers to the same (not yet created) column.  Which you cant do.  Did you mean to use Devices_PLC_ID in the second instance?